# Comparing probability of different length sequences of independent events

Tags: probability, independence, normalization

Assume I have two different datasets $D_1$ and $D_2$. Each of these datasets has a different number of samples $|D_1| = m$, $|D_2| = n$. Assume each sample is i.i.d drawn from the same underlying distribution $\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$. Then for samples $s$: $P(D_1) = \prod_{i = 1}^m p(s_i)$ and $P(D_2) = \prod_{j = 1}^n p(s_j)$.

Is it possible to normalize these two probabilities to make them comparable despite being of different lengths? I read [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/301252/normalizing-probability-of-sequence-by-its-length) post which advises adding a dummy variable, but:

1. I'm not sure this makes sense, where is the theoretical grounding?
2. Just one draw of the dummy variable is enough to compare, for example, a length 100 sequence of independent probabilities vs. a length 2 sequence of independent probabilities?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You could take the $m^{th}$ and $n^{th}$ roots of the products (respectively).  BTW I assume that you meant $P(D_2)$ in the statement $P(D_1) = \Pi_{j=1}^np(s_j)$.

Comment: Is there any theoretical basis for this?

Comment: Kind of.  The results are the geometric means of the probabilities; the geometric mean is the number for which, if all the probabilities were equal, you'd get the same total probability as you observed (since probabilities multiply instead of add...)